# How to Display the All Recent Items using lightning components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, recent-item

How to display all Recent Items using lightning components. Or any other ways to display All Recent Items in community builder home page? Can you please anybody help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard out-of-the-box component for this that you can drag-n-drop on any lightning page. See below for clarity:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do it by adding a Standard home page component in Lightning Experience named **Recent Records or Recent Items**. Click on setup and select edit page and from the standard component list add it to page and save it.

> Recent Record will show you only 5 records at a time.

Recent Items Component

> The Recent Items component displays a list of the most recently used
>   items. The default is three, but you can set it to show a maximum of
>   30. In the Lightning App Builder, you can specify which objects’ records appear in the recent items list.

The Recent Items component supports these objects, based on the specified properties:

1. All custom objects
2. All standard objects for which both of these conditions are true:

   - A compact layout is defined for the object.
   - The object is tracked in the most recently used objects list.

> NOTE:-  If a standard object meets both of these criteria but isn’t in
>   the list of available objects when you configure the component, then
>   the object isn’t supported for this component.

If an object is tracked in the most recently used objects list, one or both of the LastViewedDate or LastReferencedDate fields are present.

Reference:- [Standard Lightning Page Components](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_components.htm&type=5)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for given fast reply.. my requirement is all objects Recent Itemts are display in community cloud home page. So I need to show through lightning componets

Comment: You have not mentioned this in your question. You need to give all the details related to your requirement to us within the question to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: If any way to possible to display all recent items, then please share to me

Comment: Is it possible to display Recent Items in community cloud home page like Lightning App Builder having recent items

Comment: Anybody help on this question